# RxJS combineLatest type

Tags: angular, typescript, types, rxjs

I have written a `function` that given an `array` of `source observables` and an `enum` value, it returns a `combineLatest` of all the sources *and an observable based on the enum value*.

Here is an example:

```js
enum Animals {
    DOG,
    CAT
}

interface Animal {
    name: string,
    type: Animals
}

export observeAnimal$(type: Animals): Observable<Animal> { 
// implementation 
}

export function combineAnimal$(source: Observable<any>[] | Observable<any>, type: Animals) {
    if(source instanceof Array) {
        return combineLatest([...source, observeAnimal$(type)]);
    } else {
        return combineLatest([source, observeAnimal$(type)]);
    }
}
```

Because of how I typed `combineAnimal$`, using that `function` on `components` I lose the static type analysis that I would have if I used `combineLatest` directly. (the return type of my custom function is calculated as an `Observable` of `any` type).

Is there a way to type it better?

Comment: Maybe I am still missing something, buy why do you type the inputs of `combineAnimal$` as `Observable<any>` and not  `<Observable<Animal>>`? Also you might set an explicit return type for your `combineAnimal$`, then you get compile errors if the method is implemented in a way not fullfiling that type.

Comment: The user would use `combineAnimal$` as following:

```combineAnimal$([myObservable1$, myObservable2$], Animals.DOG).pipe(...).subscibe(...) 
```
I don't know the types of the sources that the user will pass, I just know that i will receive a list of sources, which will be observables, and i will have to combine their latest emission values to the last emission value of the requested animal.

I need a way to type my function so that, in the `subscribe`, the types that the user has set for its source observable will be preserved.

Comment: In this example

```combineAnimal$([myObservable1$, myObservable2$], Animals.DOG).pipe(...).subscibe(...) ```

if myObservable1$ emits `number` and myObservable2$ emits `string`, on the subscribe i will have an array of three elements, ```number string and Animal```. But because of how I typed my function, i will see all values as any.

Comment: Hm, if you yourself don't know the types, the compiler will also not be able to do. You might want to look into Generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html, allowing to do something like `combineAnimal$<string | number | Animal>`

Comment: Yes I think that I will need to use generics but I still can't figure out how.... I basically need to do type my custom function exactly like combineLatest does, except that the last value on the emitted array will always be of `Animal` type